# broadcast the message from one turtle to one of it link-neighbor

Tags: netlogo

I am working on project where a breed called nodes passes messages to its link-neighbors

Code:

```
ask message
[
let new-location one-of [out-link-neighbors with [hasmsg? = false]] of node-id

move-to new-location 

set node-id new-location
 ]
```

As above we can see the message [i.e. a turtle of breed message] looks for out-link-neighbors that has never received message. Once the breed: message finds such node there is a link walking which shows passing of message is done.

Now, what I want to do is, instead of moving message to new-location I want to copy the message to new-location. How do I do that I have tried following but it generates new messages at every location that does not have out-link-neighbors

```
ask message
[
let new-location one-of [out-link-neighbors with [hasmsg? = false]] of node-id

hatch-message 1 [move-to new-location] 

set node-id new-location
 ]
```

Comment: Though this doesn't answer your question, is there a reason for your model to not just include the sender-who and receiver-who in your message breed? Then you wouldn't need to worry about making copies, unless that's something that you need to model.

Comment: So ... a newly hatched message may try to move to the location of `nobody`, raising an error.  Is that the problem you are describing?

Comment: The idea of my model is to show communication over the network among different nodes.

Comment: No the problem problem is a newly hatch message should move to its out-link-neighbors only but it moves anywhere over the network and the new hatch messages are doubling every tick but the idea is it only should be copied when there is a out-link-neighbor

Comment: @ParthBrahmbhatt You must have given every message a at least one out-link neighbor.  Otherwise you should see the error I described.  This would explain why you get message doubling.  If that's right, the doubling will continue unless you break a link after each movement.